# Why is the GETDATE() function not working in IF condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created 1 code which should run only once in a day around 4 pm everyday.

The below condition I am running but it's not returning the desired output.

```
DECLARE @to_date AS date 

SET @to_date = GETDATE()

IF @to_date = GETDATE()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Tem1
        SELECT * FROM Temp2
END
```

Comment: It's working. The way this code is written though, the *actual* value may have changed from one call to the next. What are you trying to do anyway? This code doesn't make much sense - you could eliminate that `IF` entirely. If you want to schedule a job, use SQL Server Agent.

Comment: You assign it to a `date` variable which will remove the time component so even if by some miracle the two calls did return the same value they still can't be equal unless this happens at exactly midnight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetDate() is not deterministic.  This means it can (and most probably does) give you a different value in each call. Using equals with getdate() will almost always be wrong.  Try less than @to_date instead.

Comment: thank you its working with <  now  but is there a way to run it only once in a day

Comment: If you only care about the date portion you can use `CAST([YouDateField] AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` as that will truncate the time portion.  I recommend you change your process to have a processed stamp or flag instead so it can be safely reentrant multiple times a day.

Answer (score 1):

Because of [precedence rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - date is implicitly converted to datetime for comparison. You expect the opposite.